# Confusion with functions inside class in JS

Tags: javascript

I was learning classes in JS and if you look at the code below

```
class Car{
  drive(speed) {
     console.log('Drive at '+ speed)
   }
}

const car1 = new Car();
```

I defined function `drive()` inside class Car and it is clear that `drive()` is automatically attached to Car.prototype which ensures there is one copy of `drive()` and the question is if we create new instance of Car class then Is drive() copied to `car1`, if not, how is it possible to have one copy of `drive()` and by passing argument get different results.

Comment: That's how `prototype` chain works. First, `car1` will be checked for a `drive` property. If it doesn't exist, it will be looked in `Car.prototype`. If it is not found there, it will be searched in `Object.prototype` because `Object.getPrototypeOf(Car.prototype) === Object.prototype` (methods like `toString()`)

Comment: @adiga, look, if I create more objects of Car class, will each object have its own original copy of drive()

Comment: No, it won't. If you update `Car.prototype.drive = <some-other-function>`, it will affect all `Car` objects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: @adiga, but by having one copy of drive() in Car.prototype for all objects how can we customize drive() FOR EACH METHOD for example car1 has 90 as its speed car2 has 100 as its speed so drive() will output various results. Does it mean that each object has access to fresh drive() even if there is only one copy of drive(). Hope you got what I mean

Comment: because you are passing `speed` as parameter. It is not doing anything with the car instances. Since, you aren't using `this` inside `drive`, it's as if you are using `Car.prototype.drive(10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of confusion is for adding so much "*sugar*" to our classes without to know what it is happening.

Your class is defined using **ES6**

```
class Car {
  drive(speed) {
    console.log('Drive at ' + speed)
  }
}
```

Next what you do is construct an object using your class, using **new**

The first question is what the **new** keyword does?

- A new object is created, and this inherits from `Car` prototype
- **This** is attached to this newly created object

So, by doing `const car1 = new Car();`, you get a new object wherein its prototype you get the `drive` function.

In **ES5** your class is written by using a constructor function.

```
function Car() {}

Car.prototype.drive = function (speed) { console.log(speed); }
```

Now, you can do: `console.log(Car.prototype.constructor);` and you will see that the constructor function shown is Car.

If you want to create a subclass in **ES6** you use the **extends** keyword but in **ES5** what is really happening is:

```
Function SuperFastCar() {}

SuperFastCar.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
SuperFastCar.prototype.turbo = function (maxSpeed) { console.log(maxSpeed); }
SuperFastCar.prototype.constructor = SuperFastCar;
```

`Object.create` creates a new object using as the prototype the provided object. Also, we need to overwrite the `constructor`, if not `Car` constructor function will appear for `SuperFastCar`.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, yeah all is clear except for one thing. Ok, the reason for putting function into prototype is to ensure there is one instance of the function to save memory. Ok but imagine we have function with parameter and every time we create object with different parameters then output will be different. What confuses me is how car2 accesses fresh drive() since car1 already used it with different parameter. Hope it is clear

Comment: As I say, each time you create an object with  NEW a new object is created, and in the prototype of this object, the function (drive) is added, it doesn't mind if the function has or not parameters. Moreover, a function execution hasn't state unless you are using class atributes inside the function with THIS. But as I said too, the THIS is the new created object so, there is no problems with it.

Comment: ok perfect, you know, just last question why did you declare Car.prototype.drive = function (speed) { console.log(speed); } outside of the function Car?

Comment: That is what ES6 do for you when you declare a function inside a class.

Comment: yes I know but why? just what if we put Car.prototype.drive = function (speed) { console.log(speed); } INSIDE the function I think it is not good but I do not know WHY? :)

Comment: If you add the definition inside Car, each time you want to create a new object the drive function will be overwritten

Answer (score 1):

Yes is it available on instance of `Car class`, You can pass value when invoking `drive` function on any instance of `Car` class

```js
class Car {
  drive(speed) {
    console.log('Drive at ' + speed)
  }
}

const car1 = new Car();
car1.drive('50 kmph')
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, look, if I create car2 object, then will car2 have its own copy of drive(). I mean, every time I create new object will each object have its own drive() because each object has its own speed

Comment: @user11807902 `drive` is stateless function it just console.logs so your instance of `Car` is not holding any value, you will get in console.log whatever value you're passing in `drive` function

Answer (score 0):

Everything you create inside the `prototype` will be shared between all instances of the class. Keep in mind that in the methods you define inside the `prototype` you are typically defining the behaviour of your class (which should be shared between all instances).

Now, when you define a second instance of your `Car` class, both the first and the second instance share the `drive` method. But that doesn't mean that they can not call the method with different values:

```
class Car {
    drive(speed) {
        console.log('Drive at '+ speed)
    }
}

const car1 = new Car();
car1.drive('10mph'); // ---> Will log "Drive at 10mph"

const car2 = new Car();
car2.drive('15mph'); // ---> Will log "Drive at 15mph"
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, yeah all is clear except for one thing. Ok, the reason for putting function into prototype is to ensure there is one instance of the function to save memory. Ok but imagine we have function with parameter and every time we create object with different parameters then output will be different. What confuses me is how car2 accesses fresh drive() since car1 already used it with different parameter. Hope it is clear